# How to Have multiple buttons inside Android SlidingDrawer Control

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I am making a quiz application in which i am planning to use the SlidingDrawer control for displaying different question numbers. Clicking on a number will allow the user to jump to a specific question.

I have implemented the sliding drawer control but it is able to display only 6-7 buttons inside it depending on the screen size. Trying to add more buttons to it gives an exception. 
I tried using a GridView inside the SlidingDrawer but i keep getting an error.

Is there anyway i can have around 20-30 buttons inside the SlidingDrawer control arranged in a grid like manner ?

Please give suggestions on any other way i can implement similar functionality in a way that doesn't take up much screen space ?

Comment: What exception does it give you when trying to add more buttons?

Comment: What exception does it give you when you try the `GridView`? Bear in mind that the Android launcher for a long time was a `SlidingDrawer` holding a `GridView`, and so it is reasonably likely that this combination works.

Comment: Looks like the exception was due to uninitialized array. If i add around 20 buttons, i am able to see only 8-9 buttons. I tried increasing the width of the slidingdrawer but still, more buttons do not appear on the next row.

Comment: @CommonsWare This is the exception i am getting java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView. I am using layout.addView(btn[i]) to add the buttons to the GridView

Comment: That is not how to use `GridView`. You need to create an `Adapter` and associate it with the `GridView`, where the `Adapter` provides the stuff to go in the cells. https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Selection/Grid

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, as a matter of fact previous Android versions (1.6 if I'm not wrong) implemented the application Launcher that way.

Search the source for that version and you'll have a working sample.